# What is the namespace for PluginBase file in PocketMine?

Tags: php, pocketmine

I can't find the namespace for PluginBase in PocketMine-MP

I expected it to be found, but Error because it was unfound

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use pocketmine\plugin\PluginBase;`

https://github.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/blob/stable/src/plugin/PluginBase.php